# LWJGL Game Development - Rigged Model Formats

Tags: model, format, lwjgl

I'm working on my first game and find the multitude of model formats to be confusing. I need "rag-doll like" control so I believe I need a rigged model format and that animation based formats will not work.  I originally landed on Collada but have since realized this is not a modern format.

I'm starting my development in lwjgl. Any recommendations before I sink in a lot of time?  Also if you know of a maven dependency that simplifies the loading process would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collada is still a *decent* format. I use it for animation.  If you are dead set on not using it, give FBX a go.  I would recommend extracting the relevant data from the files you do use and saving it in a format that is easy to extract from, thus reducing read times.

EDIT: Take a look at the ASSIMP bindings from LWJGL

Comment: After continuing to research it does appear the FBX and ASSIMP is the way to go and was able to make progress in this direction.